# Cross validate seasonal linear model

Tags: r, regression, forecasting, cross-validation

I'm trying to perform a CV on my linear model, which has seasonal dummy variables, so i can't take a random sample.

```
y = rnorm(120,0,3) + 20*sin(2*pi*(1:120)/12) 
x = months(ISOdate(2012,1:12,1))
reg.data = data.frame(y, x)
model = lm(y ~ x, data = reg.data)
```

My CV function is:

```
cross.valid = function(model, min.fit = as.integer(nrow(model$model)*0.7), h = 1)
{
  dados = model$model
  n.rows = nrow(dados)

  results = data.frame(pred = numeric(), actual = numeric())

  for (i in seq(1, n.rows - min.fit - h + 1, by = h))
  {
   dados.train = dados[1:(i + min.fit - 1), ]
   model <- update(model, data = dados.train)

   dados.pred = dados[(i + min.fit):(i + min.fit + h - 1), -1, drop = FALSE]

   predic = predict(model, newdata = dados.pred, interval = 'prediction')
   actual = dados[(i + min.fit):(i + min.fit + h - 1), 1]
   results = rbind(results, data.frame(pred = predic[1:h, 'fit'], actual = actual))
  }

  results
}
```

Example:

```
cv1 = cross.valid(model, h = 1)
mae = with(cv1, mean(abs(actual - pred )))
print(mae)
```

The MAE values for different horizons (*h*) are too close. Is the code itself valid? Is there a better solution/package for doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is anything incorrect about your function. Investigate the `forecast` package; I suspect that it will provide many functions that you need.

I have rewritten your function concisely:

```
set.seed(1)
y = rnorm(120,0,3) + 20*sin(2*pi*(1:120)/12) 
x = months(ISOdate(2012,1:12,1))
reg.data = data.frame(y, x)

pred.set<-function(i,h) {
  train<-reg.data[1:(i + min.fit - 1),]
  test<-reg.data[(i + min.fit):(i + min.fit + h - 1),]
  pred<-predict(lm(y~x, data=train), newdata=test)
  abs(test$y - pred)
}

pred.by.horiz<-function(h) 
               mean(sapply(seq(1, nrows - min.fit - h + 1, by = h),pred.set,h=h))
```

`pred.by.horiz` matches the output of your function (and post-processing) exactly.

As you mentioned, the horizon does not appear to affect the MAE:

```
mae.by.h<-sapply(seq(nrows-min.fit),pred.by.horiz)
plot(mae.by.h,type='l',col='red',lwd=2,xlab='Horizon',ylab='Mean absolute error')
```

[image: MAE by horizon]

Perhaps you expected the the mean error would increase as the prediction horizon increases. For many time-series models this would be true, but in your linear model of months *adding more data doesn't help you predict the next point in the series* (unless you add 12 months or more).

For example, consider what happens when `h` is 1. You begin with 84 months of data, 7 points of data for each month. Now, you add one point of data, which will be the next January, and attempt to predict the result of February. But your additional point of data will only help you predict the next *January*, that is how your linear function works. Look at the summary of the model:

```
lm(y ~ x, data = reg.data)
Coefficients:
(Intercept)      xAugust    xDecember    xFebruary     xJanuary  
   17.11380    -32.74962    -17.81076     -0.03235     -6.63998  
      xJuly        xJune       xMarch         xMay    xNovember  
  -26.69203    -17.41170      2.96735     -7.11166    -25.43532  
   xOctober   xSeptember  
  -33.56517    -36.93474
```

Each prediction is made solely on the basis of two variables, the intercept, and the predicted month. So predicting one point ahead isn't any easier than predicting five points ahead. That is why the MAE isn't rising as the horizon increases the problem is in the way you modeled the data, not the MAE function.

One thing I didn't completely understand about your function is why you decided to increment the size of the train set by `h` on each iteration. It is revealing to look at what happens when you try to increment by 1:

```
# Code to increment by 1
pred.by.horiz2<-
  function(h) mean(sapply(seq(1, nrows - min.fit - h + 1, by = 1),pred.set,h=h))
mae.by.h2<-sapply(seq(nrows-min.fit),pred.by.horiz2)
plot(mae.by.h2,type='l',col='red',lwd=2,xlab='Horizon',ylab='Mean absolute error')
```

[image: MAE by horizon when incrementing h by 1]

The pattern here is complex, but you'll note that the MAE starts to decrease at 12, when the horizon is large enough that the next point can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, now everything makes sense! By the way, i'm a heavy user of the *forecast* package.